# How to force kwin to only raise one window

Tags: kwin

When I click on an entry in the dashboard, the application window expands and takes focus. This is correct. But, all other windows minimized to the dashboard also grow in the background. How to change this behavior to raise only the selected entry?

Thanks for your help

Pierre

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Kubuntu 20.10, Plasma 5.19.5